# Windows 7 C-Drive Low Disk Space

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, memory

I have clean installed windows 7 ultimate 64-bit OS, on my desktop.

Configuration: 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD Gigabyte motherboard, Nvidia graphics Card.

I have installed only few applications, which do not exceed 500MB, But When i check the c-drive is full, It has 40 GB capacity.

Does the OS is occupying the space ? Or the old unused windows version still resides in c-drive.

[image: Low Disk Space]

I have tried disk clean up tool, But it oly cleared 100MB of 40GB c-drive.

Please help me cleaning up the c-drive. Ideally i want to install android sdk in my machine.

---

**Edit**

While installing windows 7, i used `delete` option to clear the `c-partition`. Is that causing the Low Disk Space issue ?

I could have used `format` option instead of `delete`, i realized it later.

Now i am planning to increase the `c-partition` size, Is that a good idea ?

or

I have to re-install (clean) by using `format` option this time and then check the occupied space to increase `c-partition` size.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What applications did you install? Was it already that full after install? If you did a clean install how would there be another WIndows on that partition? Is there a `Windows.old` folder or similar in the root of that partition?

Comment: Win7 requirements:
16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)  If you didn't wipe the drive before the previous install would probably be in a folder called Windows.old

Comment: System Restore might be occupied check it.

Comment: You have many partitions? 40GB isn't a lot for today's standards. How many program do you have installed and of what types are they? Do you have "auto backup" running? Things to consider. If you have all your personal and working files backed up in your partitions, a fresh windows install wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I have applications few applications like `Appcelerator Studio`, `Android Studio`, `Winrar`

Comment: @Seth, There is no winodws.old folder in root directory, please check the edit.

Comment: @vembutech, i have cleared the system restore points, it freed only 200 MB !

Comment: Did you (as stupid as it sounds) try to empty our recycle bin? Did you check the size of the directories on C:\? What's the biggest one? That way you would know whenever it's the Windows directory, your user directory or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

try using CCleaner. and for android SDK or Visual Studio, your current partition is not current. Always try to keep 100GB minimum for system drive (C)

Comment: Why 100GB? That seems rather arbitrary